# How does this sorting algorithm work?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, recursion

hope you are having a good day and a good thanksgiving if you live in Canada or the US.

So I have this question that asks me to explain why this sorting algorithm properly sorts an array. However I don't really understand just how this algorithm really works.

Consider the following very simple and elegant(?) sorting algorithm:

```
SomeSort(A,b,e)
if e = b + 1 then
    if A[b] > A[e] then
        exchange A[b] and A[e]
    end if
else if e > b + 1 then
    p ←− [(e-b+1)/3]
    SomeSort(A,b,e − p)
    SomeSort(A,b + p,e)
    SomeSort(A,b,e − p)
end if
```

(a) Explain why SomeSort correctly sorts its input array A, assuming that n = e − b + 1 is
the length of the array (your argument need not be a formal proof but should be detailed enough to be
convincing).

(b) Find a recurrence for the worst-case running time of SomeSort. Give a tight (i.e. Θ) asymptotic
bound for the worse-case running time of SomeSort (Hint: for simplicity assume that n = 3 k for some
constant k).

(c) By comparing SomeSort with insertion sort, merge sort, heap-sort, and quicksort argue if this
simple algorithm is efficient.

So what I understand from this algorithm is that:

The first if statement checks if the pointers b and e are in adjacent positions with e ahead of b and if they are check if the value at b is larger. If it is then swap them the values.

The else if seems to check if e is ahead of and not adjacent to b before assigning the length of the array which is the difference between b and e before dividing it by 3 into p.

It then recurses with new pointers with b staying the same and e now being the old e minus a third of the difference between the old e and b.

It also recurses with b being the old b plus a third of the difference between the old e and b.

It then recurses one last time with the same pointers as the first recursion.

So I don't really understand why it recurses the same values twice with the e becoming e-p. I am also not really sure how recursing by a third of the difference would properly sort the array without missing anything.

If you could help me understand these recursions or anything I might be missing here, that would be great. I can't even start to answer the second part of this question of finding a worst case without understanding the algorithm, so this is really annoying me. Thanks!

Comment: First things first: write down an array on a piece of paper. Then execute the algorithm step by step. Then try a different array. It should bring you closer to understanding what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic feature that you're missing in the sort rationale is that the are of overlap (middle third of the array) is as large as the amount left out in each pass.  In the worst case, the three subsets of the array will be in opposite order: everything in the "b" third belongs in the "e" third, and vice versa.  However, with the center part being large enough to hold all of the severely mis-placed items, the three successive sorts will fix that problem.

Walk through the algorithm with

- a 3-element array, already in order
- a 9-element array, in reverse order
- a 7-element array, scrambled, such as [1, 4, 2, 8, 5, 7, 0]

At the end of this, you should understand how the algorithm works, why it works, and which are the best and worst cases.